# Did Obama call for online "truthiness tests" to "curate" news on the internet?

Tags: united-states, politics, quotes, barack-obama

I came across an [article](http://www.breitbart.com/2016-presidential-race/2016/10/14/obama-calls-truthiness-tests-media-companies/#disqus_thread) on Breitbart that cites Obama in the following ways:

> We are going to have to rebuild within this
>   wild-wild-west-of-information flow some sort of **curating function** that
>   people agree to.

> There has to be, I think, some sort of way in which we can sort
>   through information that passes some basic **truthiness tests** and those
>   that we have to discard because they just don’t have any basis in
>   anything that’s actually happening in the world.

> What we cannot do is have a situation in which suddenly this becomes
>   the Wild, Wild West.

The article includes a video. However, it's just muted footage of Obama speaking, with a woman's voice talking about what Obama allegedly said.

I've tried a few relevant search entries, however, I can't seem to find any reliable source.

Did Obama actually say any of this?

<sup>Emphasis mine.</sup>

Comment: So Obama was calling for something like skeptics.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

You can see a video from the white house on YouTube where he makes [the first statement](https://youtu.be/BikQFWNYct4?t=58m45s) and [the second statement](https://youtu.be/BikQFWNYct4?t=1h05s).

He is clearly not referring to censorship but to something similar to the [Web Of Trust](https://www.mywot.com/).

The third statement is unrelated and refers to cyberwarfare. Here's the [third statement](https://youtu.be/MAyj6yha_bE?t=38s) which continues with

> What we cannot do is have a situation in which suddenly this becomes the Wild, Wild West with countries that have significant cyber capacity start, ah, engaging in competition, unhealthy competition or conflict with these means

Comment: We already *have* Web of Trust, though. Is he talking about something more centralized like government or ISP supported? Did he (or his staff) ever elaborate, or are we left to speculate?

Comment: @Fiksdal he doesn't say, but he does say it would be optional and does not seem to imply government-controlled at all. He's more talking about having a *curating* function based on reputation of the curator, like a newspaper.

Comment: Right. Sort of like WOT, I guess. Genius.com has this really cool browser extension which lets people annotate websites sentence for sentence, and also vote on the annotations of others. Anyway, since such services already exist, I think it's unclear what Obama is calling for. More widespread use of those services, maybe? Hard to tell.

Comment: WOT got close to useless lately, as more and more activist groups find it and start putting red flags on any website they ideologically don't agree with.

Comment: @vsz Yeah, good point. And I wonder if it's even possible to avoid such tendencies?

Comment: @Fiksdal and I think that is what Obama is asking

Comment: @Mark Difficult question, in either case.

Comment: @vsz I would say that untrustworthiness is not really an ideological thing, is it? https://www.pcworld.com/article/3139814/software/web-of-trust-browser-extensions-yanked-after-proving-untrustworthy.html